# File upload from Docker container to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: django, docker, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

I'm putting together a CI/CD pipeline on GKE based on 
[this guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build) by Google.

Everything is working well, except that as it's a Django project I also need to run the collectstatic command and upload the files to Google Storage.

In the Dockerfile I have the following commands:

```
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
RUN gsutil rsync -R /home/vmagent/app/myapp/static gs://mystorage/static
```

Collectstatic works as expected, but the gsutil upload fails with the following error message:

```
ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to mystorage/static/...
```

What's the best way to authenticate gsutil?

Comment: What do you want to say by "file within Docker Container"? File created by the container at runtime? Or static files contained in the container? Where is you K8S cluster? On GCP? GKE? or elsewhere?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Sorry for being unclear, I've edited the post. The cluster is running on GKE and the files are created at runtime by the Django `collectstatic` command.

Comment: What are the default service account of your VMs? and what are the roles of this service account? Another question, how did you create the cluster? Did you use special parameters?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your docker container on GCP (GKE), you use application credentials to authenticate a pod, which then has the same permissions as that service account. More information about this can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/security-overview). Both GKE and other kubernetes clusters allow you to import key files as secrets. On all Kubernetes platforms this is done with the following commands. The full guide can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform).

```
kubectl create secret generic pubsub-key --from-file=key.json=PATH-TO-KEY-FILE.json
```

Then set the environment variable in your manifest like this:

```
 env:
    - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
      value: /var/secrets/google/key.json
```

Too bad running pods under a certain role is not yet possible. GCP operates with service accounts, not with roles like AWS. In AWS you can assign a role to a task, which grants a container permissions under that role.

Comment: Running the pod as a service account sounds promising. So do I just set `spec.serviceAccountName` to the newly created service account?

Comment: After further reading, only credentials are allowed on GKE. I updated my answer accordingly.